# Android-Gradle: Lib with different targetSDK version than application

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use this lib:

```
compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.1'
```

but it's compiled with `targetSdkVersion 19.` and my application have `minSdkVersion 15`

Usually I proceed in this way:

1. Clone prj
2. Update gradle.build (targetSdkVersion 15)
3. Create jar
4. Add jar to local maven repository
5. Add mavenLocal() repo to gradle.build of my android app

but as I am a newbie of Gradle, I want to know if exist a shortcut for this operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem uning this library. The tag `targetSdkVersion` only indicates that this code works in that API level. It's more an info tag than a restriction.

About your procedure, if you don't have to touch the library's manifest, simply import it in gradle using the line you posted, and will be fine.

PS: By the way, i've used exactly that library in a project with `minSdkVersion` 15 and works well :)

Comment: With a check on my build.gradle I found this: targetSdkVersion 18. This was the reason for the error. The libs are always built with last version. 
Thanks!